# Why is my JavaScript code not retrieving data from a website's feedback form into Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

please help me to figure out with Google Sheets. This code seems to be working, but the data is not coming from the website's feedback form.

I paste this code when creating an app in Google Sheets

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

I have this script on the site

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
     <textarea name="message" rows="6" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn2">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

```
<script>
    const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxtQncRdZtIf1og4N5BxPijVDnQ_BadYpveI11qpkCH-f-378CfN_NqmlBEYYoYqYjB/exec';
    const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet'];
    const msg = document.getElementById("msg")
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form) })
            .then(response => {
                msg.innerHTML = "Message successfully"
                setTimeout(function(){
                    msg.innerHTML = ""
                }, 5000)
                form.reset()
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error('Error!', error.message));
    });
</script>
```

I also changed the function to insert the table ID, to no avail.

```
function initialSetup() {
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID");
    scriptProp.setProperty("key", activeSpreadsheet.getId());
}
```